# System color dynamic changing in c

Tags: c, colors, system

Why I can't do thus;

```
char backgroundColor='c',textColor='e';
printf("Please, enter background color: "); scanf("%c",&backgroundColor);
printf("Please, enter text color: "); scanf("%c",&textColor);
system("color "+backgroundColor+textColor);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: For a second thing adding characters to a string like you have done `"color "+backgroundColor+textColor` doesn't do what you think it does. `"color "` is a pointer to characters. To add something to a pointer advances the pointer by the length of an element (the size of char). Print out `"color "+1` and `"color"+2` and you should observe that the beginning of the string is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add strings in C. The console colour is set by `color BF` where `B` is the background colour and `F` is the foreground (text) colour, in hexadecimal. So `color 1E` will set a blue background and yellow text. In addition `scanf` needs a space before `%c` as shown here, to clean off the `newline`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char backgroundColor='c',textColor='e';
    char sysmes[] = "color BF";

    printf("Please, enter background color: "); 
    scanf(" %c",&backgroundColor);

    printf("Please, enter text color: "); 
    scanf(" %c",&textColor);

    sysmes[6] = backgroundColor;
    sysmes[7] = textColor;
    system(sysmes);
    return 0;
}
```